# Given an array a of n integers, and q queries, for each value from index l to index r, add x to the value

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array, and for each query, I need to add x to all the values from index l to index r. For example, if I had the array `1 0 1 0 1`, and three queries of the form l, r, x:
`1 2 1 3 5 3 1 5 2`
I'd have to add 1 to values in the array from index 1 to index 2, then 3 from index 3 to index 5, then 2 from index 1 to index 5. The final array would be `4 3 6 5 6`. How would this be done efficiently? I tried simply iterating over the values from l to r, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the easy to implement solution:

Let A = [a1, a2 ..... an], be your initial array.

First build a differences array from the initial array:
Differences Array B = [a1, a2-a1, a3-a2, a4-a3 ....an-an-1]

Notice the following relation between A and B: The i th element of A is the sum of first i elements of B.

We will perform updates on the differences array.
Suppose you add x to each element of A from index L to index R.

How does this change the differences array ?

Notice  index L's difference with its previous element is increased by x.

also notice that index R+1 's difference with its previous index is decreased by x.

Furthermore, none of the other elements (other than L and R+1) have their differences with previous element altered.

So `for (int i = L; i <= R; i++) A[i] += x`, translates to `B[L] = B[L] + X` and `if (R+1 < N) B[R+1] = B[R+1]-X`

Once all queries are done. You want to construct the array A back. Since the ith element of A is the sum of first i elements of B, the following is the Code to construct A back.
`A[0] = B[0]`
`for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) A[i] = B[i]+ A[i-1]`

If you have Q update queries, Total running time is O(N+Q)

Answer (score 1):

For **mutable range queries** you should opt for **Segment Tree**

Building a segment tree will take **O(n)** time. (One time process)

Each query takes **O(log n)** time

Using this, you can achieve the results with efficiency.

Take a look here: https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html

Answer (score 0):

The naive method is to follow the instructions of shifting l, r, x into possession then iterating from `l` to `r` adding `x`

```js
var arr = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
var q = [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, 2];

while (q.length) {
  var l = q.shift();
  var r = q.shift();
  var x = q.shift()

  for (var i = l - 1; i < r; i++) {
    arr[i] += x;
  }
}

console.log("" + arr)
```

Comment: I tried this of course, but it runs very slowly. I want a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the problems of this kind, observe that each query `l, r, x` is in fact *two* queries: `l, end, x` and `r+1, end -x`.

Once you split them in in the pairs, sort them by the start index (`O(q log q)`), and obtain the result in a single `O(n)` pass.

Answer (score 0):

1. Question 1

There is an array of integers, arr, and an integer value X. For each element in another array of integers, query_values, return the 1-based index in arr of the query_values[i] occurrence of X. If X does not occur query_values[i] times, return -1 for that query.

Example

arr = [1, 2, 20, 8, 8, 1, 2, 5, 8, 0] X = 8 query_values = [100, 4, 2]

There is no 100th or 4 ^ (th) instance of X = 8 in arr. The 2 ^ (nd) occurrence is at index 5. Return [-1, -1, 5].
Function Description

Complete the function kthOccurrence in the editor.

kthOccurrence has the following parameter(s): int X: the integer to search for int arr[n] : the elements to search int query_values[q]: the occurrence of X to find the index of
Returns

int[q]: the index in arr or -1 for each query

Constraints

1 <= n q<=2^ * 10 ^ 5

• 0 <= arr X, query_values <= 10 ^ 9

Input Format For Custom Testing

The first line contains an integer, the value of X. Next line contains a single integer n, the size of arr.

The next n lines each contain an integer, arr[i]

The next line contains a single integer q, the size of query_values.

The next q lines each contain an integer, query_values[j].
Sample Case 0

Sample Input For Custom Testing

STDIN

FUNCTION

8

-> X = 8

10 -> arr[] size n = 10

1 -> arr []=[ 1, 2, 20, 8, 8 ,

1, 2, 5, 8,0]

2

20

8

8

1

2

5

8

-> -> query_values[] size q = 5 query_values[] = [100, 2, 100

5

1, 3, 4]

2

1

3

4
Sample Output

-1

5

4

9

-1

Explanation

There is no 100 ^ (th) or 4th occurrence of 8, hence, for those queries, the answer is -1. For the rest, it is the index of the kth occurrence of X = 8 .

▼ Sample Case 1

Sample Input For Custom Testing

STDIN

FUNCTION

9

-> x = 9

4

-> arr[] size n = 4

9

-> arr[]= [9, 8, 9, 9]

8

9

9

-> query_values[] size q = 4

4

-> query_values[] = [7, 3,

7

7, 6]

3

7

6
Sample Output

-1

4

-1

-1

Sample Explanation There is no 6 ^ (th) or 7 ^ (th) occurrence of 9. The 3rd occurrence is at index 4.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35723016)